# Can a data annotation discover other annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I would like to build an extended `DisplayAttribute` annotation that can detect if the property has the required attribute on it.  And, if so and a "* " in front of the name to show it is required.

Is this possible?  I can't seem to figure out how to discover if other attributes are present within an attribute.  Even if it is possible, will the `Html.Label` helper recognize it?  Or do I have to extend that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom `Html.LabelFor` will be enough. You don't need to extend the `DisplayAttribute` as you cannot access other attributes from within an attribute.